# Unable to activate RTF in Runtime Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, mule, anypoint-rtf

Following this document ( https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/latest/install-aws ) to install RTF in AWS but even after launching nodes the RTF still in "pending for activation" state?

Comment: This is not a question appropiate for Stackoverflow because it is related to the installation of third party products, it can not be reproduced by others and requires debugging. Serverfault or Superuser sites may be more appropriate. Check the help to understand what is in scope for Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic